# Как закрепить кнопку в правом верхнем углу и как добавить к ней ссылку на мой другой файл

Tags: html, ссылка

У меня есть вопрос, как закрепить кнопку в правом верхнем с помощью html? Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку перекидывало на мой другой html-файл с формой регистрации?

Всё файлы хранятся на моём компьютере. Пишу код в "Блокноте".

[image: форма Регистрации]

Код главного экрана:

```
<html lang="ru">

<head>

<meta charset="UNF-8">

<title>Главная страница</title>>>

<style>

body {

background-color: red;

h1 {

background-color: white;

}

P

background-color: red;

}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<button>Войти</button>

<h1 align="center">Bicycle House</h1

> <p align="center">Дoбpo пожаловать!</p>

<р>Этот сайт предназначен для тех, кто занимается или интересуется велоспортом. Здесь можно узнать новости о мире велосипедистов и

велосипедов.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%88%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2). Начнем с того, что Ваш HTML код не должен быть в `<head>`, а должен быть внутри тега `<body>`.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "закрепить"? Нужно что бы эта кнопка оставалась всегда на экране, даже когда вы прокручиваете страницу, или она просто должна быть справа-сверху?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .btn{
            position: fixed;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #fff;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            right: 10px;
            top: 10px;
            background-color: #000;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="btn" href="путь до вашего фаила">Войти</a>
</body>
</html>
```